# Multiple Parents for ajaxtoolkit:cascadingdropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependencies, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

I'm trying to set a filter using ajaxtoolkit CascadingDropDown. 
The problem is that I need to set a CascadingDropDown using as parent 2 others CascadingDropDown.

My code looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Parent1" runat="server"/>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CCDParent1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Parent1" ..../>

<asp:DropDownList ID="Parent2" runat="server"/>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CCDParent2" runat="server" ParentControlID="Parent1"  TargetControlID="Parent2" ..../>

and this is what I need.
<asp:DropDownList ID="Child" runat="server"/>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CCDChild" runat="server" ParentControlID="Parent1 and Parent2" TargetControlID="Child" ..../>
```

Is it possible? How?

Thanks

Comment: It is not technically possible. What do you want to achieve with this layout?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.What I'm trying to do is populate the 3rd dropdownlist from 2 different datasources based on the previous selection. I can get the same result with onselectedIndex events but not with the cascadingDropDown.

Comment: Could you provide an example of successful populating with onselectedIndex? Maybe you need to merge datasources somehow, but I still don't get the logic that is used here.